# IBM MDM Component level getParty but as per requesterTimeZone

Tags: master-data-management

We have existing code to retrieve user detail by component level getPetrson call. Perhaps the last developer did component level getPerson due to performance benefits.

But now I have requriement that all the date fields in the getPerson response must have dates in timezone as per the defined value in requesterTimeZone field.

I have 2 options

1. Convert all component level getParty into controller level and set timezone. 2. Manually write codes to convert list of 20 - 25 date field values into a timezone defined in requesterTimeZone.

Which one is really performance benificial . is there a way at component level getPerson call to set requesterTimeZone as say IST or PST but the stored value in DB is by default GMT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used the ObjectHierarchyMetadata.addHandler(BusinessObjectTimeZoneConverterHandler); & ObjectHierarchyMetadata.execute(anyBobj);
to convert a anyBObj got using component level get call.

Answer (score 1):

I will choose 1st option as per IBM standards.  Manually converting timestamp fields which avaialble in most of the BOBjs is tedious job and it is not as per recommendations. I hope you guys enabled OTS, Hence adding controller flow doesn't impact much. If your invoking getParty more than once then save the response instead of calling many times..

Are you calling at business proxy? like Maintain? 
Possible let us know the behaviour exactly.

Comment: We are calling from a custom Inquiry transaction created.

Comment: Oh ok. Then go with 1st option chandru.. Or did you handled in some other way, If so please let us know?

Comment: Finally I used the ObjectHierarchyMetadata.addHandler(BusinessObjectTimeZoneConverterHandler); & ObjectHierarchyMetadata.execute(anyBobj); to convert a anyBObj got using component level get call.